# How to personalise colour map for a contour plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have 2 sets of data, which when subtracted will give me the absolute performance of a system. Therefore there will be positive and negative values. These values are then plotted on a contour plot to understand which is best. I would like to personalise the colour bar with my own colour scheme as shown below:

-10 to -2: blue,
-2 to 2: white,
2 to 10: red.

I would also like the colours to shade with change of magnitude - so the blue starts at dark blue from -10 to light blue to -2, then white between -2 and 2 and light red to dark red from 2 to 10.

I have already managed to plot the contour plot but need to change the colour map.

(MALTAB script)

```
figure
contourf(N_X3,N_Y3,N_Z3,50,'edgecolor','none') %N_X3 is the x axis 1x9   %matrix N_Y3 is the y axis 7x1 matrix and N_Z3 is the z axis 7x9 matrix
title(d);
colormap cool %map colour style
xlabel('Peak Period (t)');
ylabel('Heading (deg)');
c = colorbar('southoutside');
c.Label.String = ('MSI%'); %This is how you label the colourbar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily generate your own colormap

```
bluewhiteredcm = ones(210, 3)
bluewhiteredcm(1:81,1)= (linspace(0,1,81))'
bluewhiteredcm(1:81,2)= (linspace(0,1,81))'
bluewhiteredcm(end-80:end,2)= (linspace(1,0,81))'
bluewhiteredcm(end-80:end,3)= (linspace(1,0,81))'
imagesc(peaks(64));
colormap(bluewhiteredcm);
```

Answer (score 0):

I add this answer since this apporach is very different from my first answer. On the long run I think this is more useful, since it allows to extend the colormaps provided by MATLAB. However, ones has to use different Colormap Selector etc., which might be too much for this question.

I use the following class to generate (linear) colormaps:

```
classdef LinearColormap < handle
%LINEARCOLORMAP   generates a linear colormap
%
% Usage:
%    cm = LINEARCOLORMAP(m) generates a m-by-3 colormap
%    
%    cm.addColor(pos, [r g b]);
%       adds the color specified by r g b to the colormap. pos should be a
%       relative position. To add at position n (with n<=m) use
%       cm.addColor(n/m, ...). If not color is specified for pos=0, black
%       is selected, if no color is specified for pos=1, white is selected.
%
%    cmap = cm.getCM();
%       returns the colormap.
%
%    cm.saveAs(filename)
%       saves the colormap as a custom colormap in the namespace
%       phutils.colormaps.custom. <filename> should be a valid matlab
%       function identifier that starts with a lowercase letter
%
% See also: phutils.colormaps.tools.rewriteColormapList 

    properties (Access = protected)
        length 
        colors
        positions 
    end
    
    methods
        function self = LinearColormap( m )
            % Generate a LinearColormapObject of size m
            self.length = m;
        end
        
        function addColor(self, pos, rgb)
            % add a color to the colormap
            %
            % Usage:
            %     
            if any(self.positions == pos)
                self.colors(self.positions == pos,:) = rgb;
            else
                self.colors(end+1,:) = rgb;
                self.positions(end+1) = pos;
            end
            
        end
        
        function cm = getCM(self)
            if ~any(self.positions == 0)
                self.addColor(0, [0 0 0]);
            end
            if ~any(self.positions == 1)
                self.addColor(1, [1 1 1]);
            end
            sorted = sort(self.positions);
            idxs = zeros(numel(sorted),1);
            for i = 1:numel(sorted)
                idxs(i)= find(self.positions == sorted(i));
            end
            cm = zeros(self.length, 3);
            pos = fix(self.positions(idxs) * (self.length-1) ) + 1; 
            colors = self.colors(idxs,:); %#ok<PROP>
            for i = 1:numel(pos)-1
                for j = 1:3
                    cm(pos(i):pos(i+1),j) = ...
                        linspace(...
                            colors(i,j),colors(i+1,j),...
                            pos(i+1)-pos(i)+1 ...
                        ); %#ok<PROP>
                end
            end
        end
        
        function saveAs(self, filename)
            % save the current colormap as
            % phutils.colormaps.custom.<filename>
            
            if strcmp(filename(1), upper(filename(1)))
                error('phutils:WrongArgument', 'Wrong argument type: First letter of filename must be lowercase');
            end
            fn = mfilename('fullpath');
            parts = strsplit(fn, filesep);
            path = fullfile(filesep, parts{1:end-1}, '+custom');
            if exist(path, 'dir') ~= 7
                mkdir (path);
            end
            
            fid = fopen(fullfile(path, [filename '.m']),'w');
            fprintf(fid, 'function map = %s (m)\n', filename);
            fprintf(fid, '    if nargin < 1\n');
            fprintf(fid, '        f = get(groot,''CurrentFigure'');\n');
            fprintf(fid, '        if isempty(f)\n');
            fprintf(fid, '            m = size(get(groot,''DefaultFigureColormap''),1);\n');
            fprintf(fid, '        else\n');
            fprintf(fid, '            m = size(f.Colormap,1);\n');
            fprintf(fid, '        end\n');
            fprintf(fid, '    end\n');
            fprintf(fid, '\n');
            fprintf(fid, '    cm = phutils.colormaps.LinearColormap(m);\n');
            for i = 1:numel(self.positions)
                fprintf(fid, '    cm.addColor(%d, [%d %d %d]);\n', self.positions(i), self.colors(i,:)); 
            end
            fprintf(fid, '    map = cm.getCM();\n');    
            fprintf(fid, 'end');
            fclose(fid);
            phutils.colormaps.tools.rewriteColormapList();
        end
    end
end
```

Usage is as follows:

```
bluewhiteredcm = LinearColormap(256);
bluewhiteredcm.addColor(0/21, [0 0 1]);
bluewhiteredcm.addColor(8/21, [1 1 1]);
bluewhiteredcm.addColor(12/21, [1 1 1]);
bluewhiteredcm.addColor(21/21, [1 0 0]);

imagesc(peaks(64));
colormap(bluewhiteredcm.getCM());
```

[image]

Note that the `saveAs` method allows to save the colormap for later use. However, you see that I use a specific namespace for that, and you might want to change this.

More information for this class can be found at [github](https://github.com/RUBION-Nanoscopy/phutils/)